# Class Reflection : Missing Properties

Tags: php, reflection, properties

I'm trying to get all properties of a Class using Reflection, but some properties are still messing.

Here a small exemple of what happens in my code

```
Class Test {
    public $a = 'a';
    protected $b = 'b';
    private $c = 'c';
}

$test = new Test();
$test->foo = "bar";
```

So at this point my **$test** object has 4 properties (a, b, c and foo).
The **foo** property is considered as a public property because I can do

```
echo $test->foo; // Gives : bar
```

On the contrary **b** or **c** are considered as private properties

```
echo $test->b; // Gives : Cannot access protected property Test::$b
echo $test->c; // Gives : Cannot access private property Test::$c
```

---

I tried two solutions to get all properties (a, b, c and foo) of my **$test** object

The first

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($test));
```

Which gives

```
array (size=2)
    'a' => string 'a' (length=1)
    'foo' => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

And the second solution

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($test);
$properties = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);
foreach($properties as $property) {
    echo $property->__toString()."<br>";
}
```

Which gives

```
Property [ public $a ]
Property [ protected $b ]
Property [ private $c ]
```

In the first case, private properties are missing, and in the second case "after instantiation" properties are missing.

No idea of what can I do to get all properties ?
(preferably with Reflection, because I also want to know if a property is public, private...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ReflectionObject` instead of `ReflectionClass` if you also need to list dynamically created object properties:

```
$test = new Test();
$test->foo = "bar";

$class = new ReflectionObject($test);
foreach($class->getProperties() as $p) {
    $p->setAccessible(true);
    echo $p->getName() . ' => ' . $p->getValue($test) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note that I've used `ReflectionProperty::setAccessible(true)` in order to access the value of `protected` or `private` properties.

Output:

```
a => a
b => b
c => c
foo => bar
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/135077)

Comment: The OP also wants the properties which were set after the object instantiation.

Comment: You are welcome. Also thanks @AmalMurali for the demo :)

Comment: @hek2mgl: +1. This would work. I've updated the answer to use `getName()` instead of `$p->name`. I've also changed the variable names to make it easier for the OP to understand it.

Comment: @hek2mgl: By the way, after your edit, you now have the same sentence repeated twice in your answer. I had already included that one just before the *Output* section, but it seems you missed that ;)